# Reduce N+1 queries in serialisation with assosiations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

Models:

```
class Audio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests, as: :item
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests, as: :item
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests

  def score_for(item)
    return 0 unless tests.where(item: item).any?

    tests.where(item: item).last.score
  end
end
```

Serializers:

```
class VideoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  attribute(:score) { user.score_for(object) }

  def user
    instance_options[:user]
  end
end
```

I try serialise lot of Video objects like this, but N+1 coming:

```
options = { each_serializer: VideoSerializer, user: User.last }
videos = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Video.all, options).serializable_hash
```

If I try this, empty array returned(looks like videos not has tests for this user):

```
options = { each_serializer: VideoSerializer, user: User.last }
videos = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Video.includes(:tests).where(tests: {user: User.last}), options).serializable_hash
```

How I can organise serialisation w/o N+1 queries problem.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you hardcoding in the user for the last snippet? That seems to be working as intended if there are no tests for that user. If you just had `Video.include(:tests)`, that will eager load tests. If you also want to eager load users you could try `Video.includes(tests: :user)`

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but anyway I want serialise Video exclusive for this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid an N+1 query if you are using a method that triggers another SQL query (in this case `where`).

The method `score_for` does another query (or 2, which would definitely need refactoring) when you invoke the relation with `where`.

One way you could change this method would be not to use relation methods but array methods over already loaded relations. This is very inefficient for memory but much less heavy on DB.

```rb
def score_for(item)
  tests.sort_by&:created_at).reverse.find { |test| test.user_id == id }&.score.to_f
end
```

You would need to load the video with its tests and the user.

Comment: Make sense, but how I can eager load tests for just this user. Tests table is huge in my case.

Comment: `tests = user.tests` would load the tests for that user. if you want videos for those tests too: `tests = user.tests.includes(:item).where(item: {item_type: 'Video'})` Make sure you have a DB index in `tests, user_id` to make this query performant